# How can I take into account multiple individuals with multiple observations across a data?

Tags: r, time-series, multilevel-analysis, bias-correction

I have a set of data as this:

```
ID V1 V2 V3
A  12 10  8
A  11  9 10
B   7 10  8
C  13 10  9
C  10 12  6
```

This dataset is from health data, where each individual takes one or more measurements (sometimes the same days, sometimes across the years), then I thought I could take into account that each individual has a weight into how the disease progress. I don't know what test can I make to know if there is enought diference between individuals to take that into account.

If there is, then I would like to get some kind of correction so these individuals can still be used with each measurement.

There is also a column with TimeStamps of each measure..

Thanks!